# Asp.net MVC 3 Filter Data then pass into JSON

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

I am using asp.net mvc 3 and was wondering is it better to pass all the data via JSON and then use javascript to filter the data or is it better to filter the data and then pass it into JSON?

If filtering the data and then passing it as JSON was the best option how would I go on doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to filter your data for security reason I suggest you to do then on both side.

You could use jquery validation like jquery.validate() pluggin and best practices find in this web site : https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

On the server side you must verify and type all data you recieve and all data you send if you are displaying data inserted by users.

MVC is secured with some process (like detection of maliscious data and antiforgery token) but control your data is always better ;).

Answer (score 0):

Well, it really depends on what you are trying to do. There are two possible cases that I see.

1. In the one case, the date you are sending to the user should only be seen by that user, or needs to be filtered ahead of time so that the user does not gain access to data that they shouldn't. In this case, you definitely want to filter server side and leverage the credential/security system provided by ASP.NET for authorization to the data.
2. A second case is where you want to keep the amount of the data small. For example,it is not typically a good idea to send huge amounts of data back and forth between client and server side. In this case, you can leverage the power of technologies like LINQ or SQL to rapidly get the data and send it back client side.
3. In the third case, you would want to send as much data as you need (and no more) to the client to allow for good client/UI interaction. That way, you can perform quick filtering, searching, or whatever client-side activity is needed. This can greatly improve user experience.

In general: limit the total amount of data you send, don't send anything the user shouldn't see (even if you aren't displaying it), and do as much work as you can client side to improve the user experience.